# How to create a variable in R indicating whether a city is a capital or not?

Tags: r, tidyverse, country-codes

I have a dataset that contains information on events taken place around world. My intention is to aggregate this data to country-year level. But before doing that, I want to create a variable "capital.city", indicating whether an event has taken place in a capital city  or not.

What I've done so far - consulting the AI Bing – is this:

```
library(countrycode)
library(maps)

# Load the world cities dataset
data("world.cities")

# Create a list of capital cities
capital_cities <- unique(world.cities$capital)

# Create a new variable indicating whether a city is a capital or not
dt_protest$capital_city <- ifelse(dt_protest$city %in% capital_cities, "capital", "non-capital")
```

But this doesn't work really - I get only non-capital values. What am I doing wrong?

Here's the sample of my data:

```
date    month   year    city    country
4/4/2006    4   2006    Lyon    France
5/23/2021   5   2021    Abeokuta    Nigeria
3/19/1996   3   1996    Kuala Lumpur    Malaysia
11/30/2006  11  2006    Moscow  Russia
11/30/2011  11  2011    Tinsukia    India
1/4/2014    1   2014    Saharsa India
11/23/2016  11  2016    Venezuela   Cuba
9/27/2019   9   2019    Shanghai    China
5/22/2003   5   2003    Bonn    Germany
12/7/2006   12  2006    Thetford    United Kingdom
9/10/2010   9   2010    New Delhi   India
11/17/2020  11  2020    Helsinki    Finland
1/22/2011   1   2011    Berlin  Germany
3/19/1993   3   1993    Jerusalem   Israel
8/2/2004    8   2004    Mumbai  India
12/9/2000   12  2000    Mumbai  India
8/29/2001   8   2001    Guelph  Canada
4/7/2003    4   2003    Seoul   South Korea
9/11/2003   9   2003    Brussels    Belgium
4/5/2006    4   2006    Hong Kong   China
2/1/2007    2   2007    Kathmandu   Nepal
10/4/2007   10  2007    Moscow  Russia
9/3/2008    9   2008    Luanda  Angola
10/21/2009  10  2009    JohannesburgSouth Africa
2/20/2010   2   2010    TashkentUzbekistan
7/20/2010   7   2010    Singur  India
10/24/2011  10  2011    SrinagarIndia
11/14/2012  11  2012    Delhi   India
1/2/2015    1   2015    Cairo   Egypt
10/13/2015  10  2015    TinsukiaIndia
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bing's AI suggestion of `capital_cities <- unique(world.cities$capital)` doesn't create a list of capital cities (surprise, AI led you astray!) - it creates a vector of integers of length 4 (`c(0, 1, 3, 2)`) which are the unique values for that column and do not take on any city names.

You are getting all non-capital values because the city value will never take on the values of 0, 1, 2, or 3, so defaults to the "else" aspect of `ifelse`, which is "not capital".

If just using the city as the indicator, you should do:

```
capitals <- unique(world.cities[world.cities$capital > 0, "name"])
```

Then you can use ab `ifelse` statement to create the new variable:

```
df <- data.frame(country = c("China", "China", "Serbia", "Serbia", "Germany", "Germany"),
                 city = c("Beibei", "Beijing", "Bavaniste", "Belgrade", "Bayreuth" ,"Berlin"))

capitals <- unique(world.cities[world.cities$capital > 0, "name"])

df["capital"] <- ifelse(df$city %in% capitals, 
                        "capital", 
                        "not capital")
```

However, this may cause a problem if there is a city in two countries where one is a capital and one is not. Paris, France and Paris, Indiana, USA  are very different places. A "safer" approach may be to use `merge` on both the city and the country:

```
capitals <- unique(world.cities[world.cities$capital > 0, c("name", "country.etc", "capital")])

capdat <- merge(df, capitals,
  by.x = c("country", "city"),
  by.y = c("country.etc", "name"),
  all.x = TRUE)

capdat$capital <- ifelse(!is.na(capdat$capital), "capital", "not capital")
```

In these data, the output are both:

```
 country      city     capital
1   China    Beibei not capital
2   China   Beijing     capital
3  Serbia Bavaniste not capital
4  Serbia  Belgrade     capital
5 Germany  Bayreuth not capital
6 Germany    Berlin     capital
```

Note the `world.cities` dataset indicates additional administrative capitals in China as 2 (municipal capital) or 3 (provincial capital) - see `?world.cities`. If you dont want to include those, change to `unique(world.cities[world.cities$capital == 1, "name"])`.

Comment: Great suggestion to use merge. Much better than Bing for sure!